# Could not launch "XXXXXX." Doesn't contain any 'remote-ios' platform architectures

Tags: xcode

I get the following error when attempting to run my app on device via Xcode:

> **Could not launch "XXXXX"**
>   '.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XXXXX.app/XXXXX' doesn't contain any 'remote-ios' platform architectures: arm64, armv7, armv7f, armv7k, armv7s, armv7m, armv7em, armv6m, armv6, armv5, armv4, arm, thumbv7, thumbv7k, thumbv7s, thumbv7f, thumbv7m, thumbv7em, thumbv6m, thumbv6, thumbv5, thumbv4t, thumb

If I look at my phone, it did install correctly, but Xcode can't launch it, meaning I can't debug it. I can run it manually on the phone, though.

It's worked before. How can I fix it so I can run the app on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the phone.

I tried the following:

- ❌ Delete app on phone and try running again
- ✅ Restart phone

Other things I was going to try if it still didn't work:

- Restart Xcode
- Delete derived data